# How do you pass a manager variable and another variable to target function in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I would like to pass 2 manager dictionaries along with another variable to a target function in multiprocessing:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
def f(x, d1, d2):
    d1[x] =  2*x
    d2[x] =  x*x
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = [1, 2, 3, 4]

    manager = mp.Manager()
    d1 = manager.dict() 
    d2 = manager.dict()

    MAX_PROCESSES = 4
    pool = mp.Pool(MAX_PROCESSES)
    pool.map(f, (x, d1, d2))
```

In so doing, I would like `process[i]` to get `x[i]`, and all 4 processes to share the dictionaries `d1` and `d2`.

However I get the following error:

> TypeError: f() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'd1' and 'd2'

Comment: @mkrieger1 I did that and got the following error: TypeError: map() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` and [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) to create an iterable where one of the arguments is an iterator and the other arguments are repeated

```
pool.map(f, zip(x, itertools.repeat(d1), itertools.repeat(d2)))
```

Comment: I get the same error, I think the issue has to do with the fact that d1 and d2 are shared variables across the processes as they are spawned using Manager()